# What command line tool can extract images from SWF files?

Tags: windows, software-rec, flash, command-line, swf

I'm desperately searching for a command line tool that allows you to extract images from an SWF file. I'm only interested in the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWFExtract from http://www.swftools.org/download.html is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd seen SWFTools, but I somehow missed Extract! Doh.

Comment: Site doesn't exist anymore :(

Comment: @GerardoLima the state of the art has probably advanced in the last 10 years beyond swftools but the site linked still loads for me? 

Comment: Thank you, @crazysim; probably. there was a transient error with my connection to Internet.